# Timeouts in mongos

Tags: .net, mongodb, sharding

in our MongoDB Cluster (3 mongos, 3 data-replicas, 3 config-replicas) sometime application catch errors like this

**2020-09-17 16:25:47,2547 [48] () ERROR
An unhandled exception has occurred: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server.
MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server.
---> MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while receiving a message from the server.
---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.**
---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error)
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.GetResult(Int16 token)
at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.ValueTaskSourceAsTask.<>c.<.cctor>b__4_0(Object state) --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Misc.StreamExtensionMethods.ReadBytesAsync(Stream stream, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.ReceiveBufferAsync() --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.ReceiveBufferAsync() at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.ReceiveBufferAsync(Int32 responseTo, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.ReceiveMessageAsync(Int32 responseTo, IMessageEncoderSelector encoderSelector, MessageEncoderSettings messageEncoderSettings, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.CommandUsingQueryMessageWireProtocol`1.ExecuteAsync(IConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.IsMasterHelper.GetResultAsync(IConnection connection, CommandWireProtocol`1 isMasterProtocol, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.ConnectionInitializer.InitializeConnectionAsync(IConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelperAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
....

at this time in mongos-log (log level=3)
many timeouts like this

**2020-09-17T16:25:47.094+0300 D NETWORK [TaskExecutorPool-0] Timer received error: CallbackCanceled: Callback was canceled**

Complete logs I can provide.

When we connect directly to data-replicas - we have no prolem like this, problem is not reproduced.
So we need to investigate - what is the reason of this timeouts, when we working with mongos?

Application and mongos working on the same Windows-servers (Windows 2012 R2).
Data and config replicas working on others Linux-servers (4.1.12-124.32.1.el7uek.x86_64).
MongoDB version 4.0.12.

I’ve asked before in https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-50942, but they recommended to ask in this community…

Please, help us to find a reason of this timeouts…

Comment: The most obvious reason is your network is not reliable.

Comment: But application and mongos on the same servers - no network between them. Or you meaning network between mongos and data-replicas?

Comment: Increase mongos log verbosity & review the log for clues. You are getting timeouts on loopback connections?